# ArrayBuffer extracted from HTML canvas is different from the ArrayBuffer that was decoded and loaded onto it using UTIF

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, tiff, arraybuffer

My goal was to load a TIFF image onto a HTML canvas. The front-end receives an ArrayBuffer of the TIFF image and I was able utilize UTIF to decode the ArrayBuffer and render it on the HTML canvas. However another functionality requires me to export the canvas contents. For this I'm using UTIF again for encoding it back to ArrayBuffer which I will then pass onto back-end server to use.

My functional scenario is:

1. Load a TIFF image onto canvas.
2. Add other objects on canvas. For eg. circle, strokes, triangles etc. (ignored in the code below)
3. Export the canvas content as a TIFF image.

Code to add ArrayBuffer:

```
private _addArrayBufferAsImageOnCanvas(buffer: ArrayBuffer, meta?: {}) {
    console.log(buffer); // 8 MB input
    // Using UTIF.js to decode the array buffer and convert it to ImageData
    const ifds = UTIF.decode(buffer);
    const timage = ifds[0];
    UTIF.decodeImage(buffer, timage);
    const array = new Uint8ClampedArray(UTIF.toRGBA8(timage));
    // Forming image Data
    const imageData = new ImageData(array, timage.width, timage.height);
    // a temporary canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = timage.width;
    canvas.height = timage.height;
    // on which we draw the ImageData
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    // Get the image data
    const outImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // and use UTIF to encode the image 
    const binaryTiffImage = UTIF.encodeImage(outImageData.data, outImageData.width, outImageData.height);
    // output
    console.log(binaryTiffImage); // 16 MB output
  }
```

The size/byte length of the `buffer` which is the input argument is half of the size/byte length of the `binaryTiffImage` which is extracted from the canvas. (8MB input, 16MB output)

Is it because UTIF encoding does not compress the array? (https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js/blob/master/README.md#utifencodeimagergba-w-h-metadata)

Is there a way I can get the exact same ArrayBuffer from the canvas as it was loaded?

Answer (score 1):

For the twice bigger output than the input, yes, the compression is probably the biggest problem.

However, there is anyway no way to get the exact same file from what you are doing, even when compressing the image's data.

First, the compressor would need to use the exact same settings as were used originally, this may or may not be possible, but not simple in any way.

Then, you are losing all the metadata from your original TIFF file. Your process only extracts the raw bitmap data, but all information that could be embedded inside this TIFF (EXIF, jpeg preview etc.) are lost.

Not only metadata are lost, but color profiles and color depth are also lost, your code converts whatever your originally had in your TIFF to sRGB, @32Bits (24bits + alpha).

If your image data was using a loosy compression like JPEG (while it's rare, it's possible), then you created new data by converting what was agglomerated data as now single pixels.

---

But even if you were using uncompressed raw pixel data @32bits, already with sRGB color profile and able to place back all the original metadata, you'll still face one big problem:

**The 2D canvas API is loosy:**

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = 50;

const input = new Uint8ClampedArray(50 * 50 * 4);
crypto.getRandomValues(input); // fill with noise

const input_img = new ImageData( input, 50, 50 );
ctx.putImageData(input_img, 0, 0);
const output = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50).data;

const are_different = input.some( (input_value, index) => output[ index ] !== input_value );

console.log( 'input and output are', are_different ? 'different' : 'same' );
// check from your browser's dev-tools
console.table( [input, output] );
```

To be fair, since this is due to alpha pre-multiplication, if you only had fully opaque pixels only, that shouldn't happen, but all these points only add up.